# How to use SHELL_PLUS_DONT_LOAD? django-extensions==1.6.1, Django==1.9.2

Tags: python, django, django-extensions

I have the following setting:

```
SHELL_PLUS_DONT_LOAD = ['django.contrib.auth.models.User']
```

However, when I run `python manage.py shell_plus` this model is still loaded.

```
# Shell Plus Model Imports
from [Redacted] import [Redacted]
from [Redacted] import [Redacted]
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission, User
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
# Shell Plus Django Imports
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import transaction
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db.models import Avg, Count, F, Max, Min, Sum, Q, Prefetch, Case, When
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.cache import cache
```

Any hints or clues about how to debug this?

Comment: Can you also try running it from the command line to see if it behaves differently? `./manage.py shell_plus --dont-load app1 ` http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/shell_plus.html#configuration

Comment: that's a good sanity check, lemme give that a try and see if i can get it working form cli.

Comment: @djq same behavior, I even tried one of my own, just in case there was a bug related to django.contrib like an order issue with middleware being loaded.  It looks like this version of `djang-extensions` was released in December, so I would assume I would have seen this reported by now if it was a bug. Looks like i'm going to have dig through the source to figure out what it's doing, i'm sure it's user configuration error.

Answer (score 0):

"When referencing nested modules, e.g. somepackage.someapp.models.somemodel, omit the package name and the reference to models. For example:"

```
SHELL_PLUS_DONT_LOAD = ['someapp.somemodel', ]  # This works
SHELL_PLUS_DONT_LOAD = ['somepackage.someapp.models.somemodel', ]  # This does NOT work
```

Source: https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shell_plus.html